# Kubuntu 20.04 Login Screen scaling

Tags: kubuntu, login

I have recently had to reinstall Kubuntu 20.04.
I am using HDMI to a HDTV and I have set the scaling to 112.5%.  This works great, but the login screen is super small.   I have checked around online, and I see several references to adding in settings to the sddm.conf, but I am not finding that in Kubuntu 20.04 in /etc/.
I had corrected this in the past, but sadly I did not bookmark my reference, and my google skills seem off from that time.

Additionally, I have 'lines' that show up when I open a terminal, and seem to shift when I move the cursor.  These line are a thin horizontal view of the screen below. I believe that this is also related to settings in sddm.

I have tried a few nvidia drivers, but no change.

If you can point an ol fool in the correct direction, it would be much appreciated.

Best regards and stay safe

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to follow up with a solution that worked for me, with hopes it will help others.

For the login screen scaling, the sddm.conf was not found, but a post I had read pointed me to -> `sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf`

At the bottom of the config file, I placed in:

```
[X11]
ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 96

  <-- your number may need to be different.
```

For reference, this is the full config of that file - yours may be different, and I only added the [X11] and the line below that.

```
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
Session=
User=

[General]
HaltCommand=
RebootCommand=

[Theme]
Current=Nordic

[Users]
MaximumUid=60000
MinimumUid=1000

[X11]
ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 96
```